# How to Set Up a Download Directory Using jQuery

Tags: jquery

jQuery supports file select capability for uploading files (below code ) but I just wonder can we do something different to set a download `directory/path` to a specific folder by using the windows select folder box?

```
<form>
<input type="file" />
</form>
```

Comment: A download directory ? What do you mean ? You'd like to choose the directory on the user's computer ?

Comment: Yeah... well... you **can't**.

Comment: This is a Browser / Operating system related question. jQuery has no control over the default download folder.

Comment: Hi Nurgle, how about setting default Download directory? is it possible?

Comment: I really do not understand why some people are putting negative point on this question?!

Comment: Because it is not considered a good question according to the TOS of SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. The user's browser settings determine where files are saved, not the website:

[image]